# how to change var value present in .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

[wants to change value dynamically like it would be reflected from DB at run time... the code shown in image is in .aspx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAPXl.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text in the question instead of a link.

Comment: ... And post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare one protected variable in code behind. Set its value from database.

```
protected variable_name as string = "12, 45, 54"
```

In your aspx file, you use that variable like,

```
data: [<%= variable_name%>]
```